# Are singleton sets closed under any topology because they have no limit points?

Tags: general-topology

From Munkres' *Topology*:

1. Let $X$ be a topological space and $x \in X$. We say that $x$ is a limit point of $A \subset X$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in some point other than $x$ itself.
2. A subset of a topological space is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points

I want to prove that singleton sets are closed in any topology.

(I'm just learning about this so I might have misinterpreted some definitions)

---

**Attempt:**
Let $\{x\} \subset X$ be a singleton set. We have that $\{x\} \setminus \{x\} = \emptyset$, so in fact no set intersects $\{x\}$ in a point other than $x$.

Since $x$ is the only point in $\{x\}$ and not a limit point of $\{x\}$, it follows that $\{x\}$ has no limit points.

Let $B$ denote the set containing the limit points of $\{x\}$.

The statement "$\{x\}$ contains all its limit points" can then be stated as $B \subset \{x\}$.

The statement

$\{x\}$ contains all its limit points $\Rightarrow \{x\}$ is closed

can be written as

$B \subset \{x\} \Rightarrow \{x\}$ is closed.

This is a true statement.

But $B = \emptyset$, hence $B \subset \{x\}$ is always true.

Therefore, $\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: Let $X=\{0,1\}$, and let $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\}$; $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ (called the *indiscrete topology*). The only open set that contains $1$ is $X$, which also contains $0$, so $1$ is a limit point of $\{0\}$. In this case $B=X\nsubseteq\{0\}$.

Comment: "Points are closed" is a nontrivial condition called being $T_1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space You simply have not shown, and it's simply not true, that $x$ is the only limit point of $x$.

Comment: For example, in a set, X, containing more than one point with the "indiscrete topology", in which the only open sets are X itself and the empty set, singleton sets are neither open nor closed.  Of course this is not a "metric" nor even "metrizable" space.  In all metric spaces, all singleton sets are closed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So a singleton set $\in \bf{R}^{2}$ cannot be closed, right? I am just piggybacking here because the OP's question is very similar to what I want to ask. If this should be a separate question, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only know that $x$ is not a limit point of $\{x\}$, you **do not** know if some other $y \neq x$ isn't a limit point of $\{x\}$. If $X=\Bbb Z^+$ and its topology is $\{\emptyset,X\}$ (the trivial/indiscrete topology) and $x=1$ then $2,3,4,\ldots$ are all limit points of $\{1\}$ because the only open set that contains $2$ (or $3$ etc) is $X$ and $X$ intersects $\{1\} - \{2\} = \{1\}$. So the set of limit points of $\{1\}$, denoted by $\{1\}'$, is just $X-\{1\}$. $1$ is an isolated point of $\{1\}$ and not a limit point, and the closure of $\{1\}$ is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if, for all open sets $U\ni a$, $U\cap A\setminus\{a\}\ne \emptyset$. In the case $A=\{x\}$, it is entirely possible that some $y\ne x$ has all its neighbourhoods satisfy $U\cap\{x\}\setminus\{y\}\ne\emptyset$ (i.e. that $x$ is in all the neighbourhoods of $y$ despite $y\ne x$). If this is the case, then $y$ is a limit point of $\{x\}$ and $y\notin\{x\}$.