# Is the statement "A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points" vacuously true for a singleton?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have come across the statement:

*"A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points".*

on MSE. The limit point (in my understanding) of a set $P\subset X$ is a point $p\in X$ whose every neighborhood contains a point in $P$ other than $p$ itself. With this definition the singleton, $\{p\}$, has no limit points. Singletons are closed (in the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$. Why is this not a contradiction?

Comment: What is your definition of a "limit point"?  Isn't $x$ a limit point of $\{x\}$?

Comment: It depends. The definition in Baby Rudin says it isn't.

Comment: @MJD Which is why I asked what the definition being used here is...

Comment: While we're at it, what is your definition of "closed"?

Comment: @curiosity  This question has already been asked and answered before on the site.  See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828923/

Comment: @XanderHenderson My definition of closed is being the complement of an open set in the usual topology in $R$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thanks for the link. I will check it out. That discussion might be a bit over my head :)

Comment: The header asks if it is vacuously true, the body asks if it is a contradiction.

Comment: Suggested reading: clopen sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set

Comment: "Why is this not a contradiction?"  Why would it be a contradiction?  If a set has no limit points, as your title suggests then it is vacuously satisfying the definition of a closed set.

Comment: @MW I think you just answered my question with this comment. Thank you. I am an engineer so I just needed a confirmation from mathematicians. Thank you all.

Comment: @MW Would you kindly post your comment as the answer? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a set has no limit points, then as your title suggests, it is vacuously satisfying the definition of a closed set. So there is no contradiction in this case.

The important point here, which many mathematicians take for granted but which we sometimes forget can be a little bit hard for others to swallow, is that in math, “vacuous” truth is not considered any less true than any other kind of truth.

When we say $A$ is defined to be closed if it “contains all its limit points” that logically translates into “For all limit points $x$ of $A$, $x\in A$.”

Crucially, in math, every “for all” statement is treated as only an assertion that there are no counterexamples, so the latter statement translates to “There are no limit points of $A$ which fail to lie in $A$.”  In the case that $A$ is a singleton (in $\mathbb R$, or more generally, in a metric space, or even more generally, a so-called $T_1$ space), we can see that there are no limit points at all, hence certainly none that fail to lie in $A$.

For a little more general discussion of why mathematics deals with vacuous truth this way, you might also check out [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2723913/1210477).

Comment: In general $\{ x\}$ is not closed. This is true for $X = \mathbb R$. Spaces $X$ in which all  singletons are closed are called $T_1$-spaces. For example, if $X$ carries the trivial toploogy, then the closure of each singleton is the whole space $X$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, OP had mentioned $\mathbb R$, but in any case I have edited to clarify.